# How is the 24 hour percent change on Binance calculated

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, binance

When it comes to 24h Change on a specific Pair,

[image]

How is this calculated?

If it's price at current time compared to price 24 hours ago, then for example:

the current price of BTC `9431` now (6/16/2020 5pm) is compared to the price of `9357` on 6/15/2020 at 5pm?

and an hour later (6pm) if I see it again will be compared to the price on 6/15/2020/6pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer you to this link: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67438/24-hour-price-change-mean

> The 24h % change is the difference between the current price and the
> price 24 hours ago.
>
> The current price of bitcoin is $14988 and was $14937 24h ago. So the
> 24h change is +0.3%, even if there was a huge spike between this
> period of time.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we have `t_0 (price now)` and `t_24 (price 24hours ago)` so then:

```
price_change(%) = ((t_0 - t_24) / t_0) * 100
```

And this would give you the percentage of the 24h change.